# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PatientVisitDetailsController#auto_build

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have models

```
class PatientVisitDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :procedure_code
  scope :billable, -> { includes(:procedure_code).where('procedure_codes.type_code IN (6,7)')}
end
```

And

```
class ProcedureCode < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :patient_visit_details, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

When I pass query for search record like

```
patient_visit_details.includes(:procedure_code).where("procedure_codes.type_code IN (6,7)")
```

Then following error comes

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'procedure_codes.type_code' in 'where clause': SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `patient_visit_details` WHERE `patient_visit_details`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND (patient_visit_id > 0) AND `patient_visit_details`.`patient_visit_id` = 6 AND (procedure_codes.type_code IN (6,7))
```

The type_code is present in the database but still getting unknown column.

Comment: try to change `patient_visit_details` to the class name: `PatientVisitDetail`. i.e.: `PatientVisitDetail.includes(:procedure_code).where("procedure_codes.type_co...`

Comment: @SunnyK I tried already and still getting same error

Comment: what about changing the `includes` to `joins`: `PatientVisitDetail.includes(:procedure_code).where("procedure_codes.type_co...`